# How can we get current date and time without using datetime module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

For exploring purpose, I want to find some another way to get date and time. So, Is there any other way to get our current date and time without using `datetime` module in python 3+?

Comment: What are you hoping to practice? This is like practicing boxing with your hands tied behind your back.

Comment: The answer is yes. Glad I could help.

Comment: yes, one way to do it i guess would be windows API calls but not sure what you are hoping to gain by doing this exercise.

Comment: @Sean: Making OS API calls would require using a module.

Comment: @martineau i know, but they would not be the `datetime` and `time` modules he wants to strangely avoid using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you don't want to use `datetime`, at minimum you still have to use `time`.

```
import time
current_time = time.ctime()
print(current_time)
```

Mon Jan 31 15:17:37 2022